# Python XML Element Tree checking issue

Tags: python, xml, for-loop, elementtree

i've an issue with my script in python. i'm using it to read an xml for e-invoice, and works fine for 99% of the field. (i' grab information from xml and put it on xls file) however, i have an issue with this part of the script. If the script find the node no issue, it will report correctly. but if not, i want the script to check the second part, of the node, and grab the information from an other field(the first field is expire date) the second field in case the first is n/a is Days for payment.

```
   for scadenza in obj.iterfind('FatturaElettronicaBody/DatiPagamento/DettaglioPagamento/DataScadenzaPagamento'):
                        print(scadenza.text) #print thee expiration date               
                        if (not scadenza.text):
                           for scadenza1 in obj.iterfind('FatturaElettronicaBody/DatiPagamento/DettaglioPagamento/GiorniTerminiPagamento'):
                             from datetime import timedelta, date
                             d1 = datem + timedelta(days=int(scadenza1.text))
                             print(f'New Expire {d1}')
                             scadenza.text = d1
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve],

Comment: scadenza is expiration date, scadenza1 is day to expire date.

Answer (score 0):

i did by myself.

```
if len(obj.findall('FatturaElettronicaBody/DatiPagamento/DettaglioPagamento/DataScadenzaPagamento')):
                        for scadenza in obj.iterfind('FatturaElettronicaBody/DatiPagamento/DettaglioPagamento/DataScadenzaPagamento'):
                            from datetime import datetime
                            print(scadenza.text)
                            self.worksheet.write(row, column + 8, scadenza.text)
                            newscad = scadenza.text[0:10]
                            scad1 = datetime.strptime(newscad, "%Y-%m-%d")
                    else:
                        for scadenza1 in obj.iterfind('FatturaElettronicaBody/DatiPagamento/DettaglioPagamento/GiorniTerminiPagamento'):
                             from datetime import timedelta, date, datetime
                             scad1= datem + timedelta(days=int(scadenza1.text))
                             print(f'New Expire {scad1}')
                             newdate = datetime.strftime(scad1, "%Y-%m-%d")
                             self.worksheet.write(row, column + 8, newdate)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).